# Windows iot core send data to remote server 52.139.250.253 costs network

Tags: uwp, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I wrote a program to collect data and transfer it to my server by a 4g router. but I find the windows IoT core send and receive data from server 52.139.250.253，it costs lots of networks, I search a lot, can not find useful information, I do not know what happen，how can I disable it?

[image: screenshot]

this is my code，pretty simple

```
 public class TcpConnection:IConnection
{
    Socket _TcpClient;
    IPEndPoint _ServerIp;
    string _IpOrUrl = string.Empty;
    int _PortNO;
    Boolean IsRecieve { get; set; } = false;
    private event Action<byte[]> DataRecieved = null;
    private int _TcpTimeout { set; get; } = 5000;
    public TcpConnection(string ipOrUrl, int portNO)
    {
        _ServerIp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipOrUrl), portNO);
        _TcpClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _TcpClient.SendTimeout = this._TcpTimeout;//等待测试
        this._IpOrUrl = ipOrUrl;
        this._PortNO = portNO;
        this.ConnectAsync();
    }

    public async void ConnectAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_TcpClient.Connected)
            {
                await this._TcpClient.ConnectAsync(_ServerIp);
                AsynRecive();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
    private void AsynRecive()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        _TcpClient.BeginReceive(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, asyncResult =>
        {
            try
            {
                int length = this._TcpClient.EndReceive(asyncResult);
                if (length > 0)
                {
                    byte[] bytesBack = data.Take(length).ToArray();
                    try
                    {
                        DataRecieved.Invoke(bytesBack);
                    }
                    catch (Exception Ex)
                    {
                        LogHelper.Log(Ex.Message.ToString(), LogLevel.Debug);
                    }
                }
                AsynRecive();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }, null);
    }
    public Boolean Send(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!this.IsConnect())
            {
                if (this.Reset())
                {
                    this._TcpClient.Send(data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this._TcpClient.Send(data);
            }
        return true;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }


    public void Close()
    {
        this._TcpClient.Close();
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_TcpClient.Connected)
            { 
                this._TcpClient.Connect(_ServerIp);
               AsynRecive();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        { }
    }

    public bool IsConnect()
    {

        return _TcpClient.Connected;
    }

    public void AddRecieveHandle(Action<Byte[]> dataEvent)
    {

        this.DataRecieved -= dataEvent;
        this.DataRecieved += dataEvent;
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Boolean Reset()
    {
        try
        {
            _TcpClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            _TcpClient.SendTimeout = this._TcpTimeout;
            this.Connect();
            return true;
        }
        catch {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public Task<bool> SendAsync(byte[] data)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Do you use the Windows Push Notification Service (WNS) in the process of sending data? The IP address you mentioned is the Microsoft uses to verify the request. If the related service is used, this is inseparable.

Comment: hi,i do not use wns to send data,i use tcpip to send data to my server,maybe there are some others apps installed use wns?

Comment: Hi, this is also the same point I have considered. Can you write the code that send the data, please? (do not include any private information)

Answer (score 0):

Have you notices the DNS lookup in your dump just before the connection is initialized. Take a look if this is used to resolve a domain to this ip address.
If it does, it looks like it has something to do with WNS (Windows Push Notification Service): https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/mt187203.

Comment: i do not user wns to send data,i blocked it ip address on the 4g router ,but i see it still send data to 52.139.250.253,and an new ip address.5m-10m per day

Comment: May i know if you have a connection with Azure or other service in your program?When you stop your custom program, can you also get the same log?